# Spring's high TTFB time only on first request

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have a Spring 4.3.6 App running on backend with Angular 2 on frontend. Every time after the server is initialized, the first request the server responds have a high TTFB (time to first byte), if compared with the subsequent requests.[TTFB delay on the first request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2NWd.png)

I verified that right on the first request I got a high peak in my computer's processor. Below is my login method in my UserController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json) throws ServletException {

    if (json.get("stUserLogin") == null || json.get("stUserPassword") == null) {
        throw new ServletException("...");
    }

    String userLogin = json.get("stUserLogin");
    String userPassword = json.get("stUserPassword");

    UserBean userBean = userService.findByUserLogin(userLogin);

    if (userBean == null) {
        throw new ServletException("...");
    }

    if (!userPassword.equals(userBean.getStUserPassword())) {
        throw new ServletException("...");
    }

    return Jwts.builder().setSubject(userLogin).claim("roles", "user").setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();
}
```

This is my UserService's find user method:

```
@Override
public UserBean findByUserLogin(String stUserLogin) {
    return userDAO.findByStUserLogin(stUserLogin);
}
```

And finally my DAO's method:

```
UserBean findByStUserLogin(String stUserLogin);
```

On the first request, I verified a high amount of milliseconds expended in the Service's method, but I still have no clue about the reason behind all this.

It is worth mentioning that this happens with every mapped method, but with different scales.

I don't know if I provided enough information about this issue. Any help will be well received, thank you in advance.

Comment: A new database connection being opened? For subsequent requests it may be taken from the pool which is faster.

Comment: That could be it, but I don't know how to be sure. I'm using MySQL and the connection configuration is defined in my application.properties file. Is there a way to ensure that this connection will be already opened by the server's start?

Comment: One way would be to change a real DAO talking to a real pool+database with a mock DAO which just returns some data sane enough to not crash your application and then test the resulting application.

Comment: With a mock DAO the TTFB was reduced from 700ms to around 100ms on the first call, it seems this is the way. Only need to know how to solve it now.

Comment: What connection pool do you use? For DBCP https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html you could play with `initialSize`/`minIdle` configuration variables to make the pool create some connections on startup.

Comment: Yes, i'm using DBCP. I defined this variables in my application.properties file, as spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size = 6 and spring.datasource.dbcp2.min-idle = 6. But the problem still persists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581201/how-to-preinitialize-dbcp-connection-pool-on-startup They advise the following: 'Try adding init-method="getLoginTimeout" to your bean' (the pool bean, I guess); that should force the pool initialization.